# How can I add a conditional field

Tags: plone, dexterity

I would like to have one field appear conditionally based on the value of another. How should I go about achieving this in dexterity?

E.g. One field is a boolean: Is the resource for sale?

If this is set as "yes" I'd like the next field to show up, being an integer- the price of the resource.

If I had to guess, I'd start hacking a javascript solution but I'm assuming there is a technique for doing it in an organised manner, but I can't find anything.

I should also mention that I am doing this to simplify the process of searching through this content later (using eea.facetednav) in which I don't know how to have a boolean search interface return results based on if the integer is > 0.

Comment: Archetypes or Dexterity?

Comment: Doing it with javascript is so trivial, I'm not sure why anything more is needed.

Comment: Dexterity, sorry I only tagged it. Steve, I guess it just seems like bad practice to not have a generic handlers for dependency so that conditions can be set in the type's model not over in the theme. Since I have no idea how to implement something like that, I guess javascript is a pretty good option. Thanks ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't checked the tags.
So, @SteveM is right, JS is the better/simplest way, however if you must be sure that users will nod populate an hidden field you must also provide a server-side check (but probably JS is enough)